# Could you please tell me the reason for not reading observations from read.csv() in R?

Tags: r

When I read the file using read.csv(file.choose()) then I'm getting following warning message and observations are not read in the object:

```
h11<-subset(h1, `Date.received` >= ("2012/04/01") & `Date.received`<=("2016/06/30"))
```

> Warning messages: 1: In Ops.factor(Date.received, ("2012/04/01")) :   ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors 2: In Ops.factor(Date.received, ("2016/06/30")) :   ‘<=’ not meaningful for factors.

But if I used path in read.csv() then it works fine. Could you please tell me the reason for it?

Comment: Did you pass other parameters to `read.csv()` when hard coding the file path? Is this in the same R session? It seems very unlikely that those two read.csv's should perform differently. Seems like you might be leaving something else out.

Comment: It seems like your `Date.received` column is `factor`, not `Date` class. Did you set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when using `read.csv` and convert the `Date.received` column to `Date` class?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that 'Date.received' is in Date format , your code could be fixed by converting your character strings to Dates:

```
h11<-subset(h1, `Date.received` >= as.Date("2012/04/01", '%Y/%m/%d') & 
`Date.received`<= as.Date("2016/06/30", '%Y/%m/%d'))
```